# Sending Msg to Whatsapp using Number from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, whatsapp

Is it Possible to send whatsapp from the number stored in database(SQLite)
SO Far I have tried sending a whatsapp from older post but its sending ony msgs or opening only contacts when i am combining both I am not getting any result
//This Will Open Specific Contact on Whatsapp

```
void openWhatsappContact() {
    String number = "919033152265";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
}
```

//This Will Send Specific Msg to WhatsAPP

```
public void SelectContactAndMsgSend(View view) {

    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (waIntent != null) {
        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}
```

//Combining Both Not getting Any result

```
public void CombiningBoth(View view) {
    String number = "Here GOes My Number"; //As i am from india my number Im putting is 91xxxxxxxxxx
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);

    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (waIntent != null) {
        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, ""));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: Hey! Have you find a solution?

Comment: I dint find any solution to work with existing whatsapp api in the mobile the only way to do is to create the whatsappapi and using it with my software.
1) WhatsAppApi in c# easily available at github
2) Convert That code to Android
3) And then use it as u like